# Find From/To Dates across multiple rows - SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to "book" within range of dates, but you can't book across gaps of days. So booking across multiple rates is fine as long as they are contiguous.

I am happy to change data structure/index, if there are better ways of storing start/end ranges.

So far I have a "rates" table which contains Start/End Periods of time with a daily rate.

e.g. Rates Table.

```
ID  Price   From        To
1   75.00   2015-04-12  2016-04-15
2   100.00  2016-04-16  2016-04-17
3   50.00   2016-04-18  2016-04-30
```

For the above data I would want to return:

```
From        To
2015-04-12  2016-4-30
```

For simplicity sake it is safe to assume that dates are safely consecutive. For contiguous dates `To` is always 1 day before `from`.

For the case there is only 1 row, I would want it to return the From/To of that single row.

Also to clarify if I had the following data:

```
ID  Price   From        To
1   75.00   2015-04-12  2016-04-15
2   100.00  2016-04-17  2016-04-18
3   50.00   2016-04-19  2016-04-30
4   50.00   2016-05-01  2016-05-21
```

Meaning where there is a gap `>= 1 day` it would count as a separate range.
In which case I would expect the following:

```
From        To
2015-04-12  2016-04-15
2015-04-17  2016-05-21
```

## Edit 1

After playing around I have come up with the following SQL which seems to work. Although I'm not sure if there are better ways/issues with it?

```
WITH grouped_rates AS 
(SELECT
  from_date,
  to_date,
  SUM(grp_start) OVER (ORDER BY from_date, to_date) group
FROM (SELECT
        gite_id,
        from_date,
        to_date,
        CASE WHEN (from_date - INTERVAL '1 DAY') = lag(to_date)
            OVER (ORDER BY from_date, to_date)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END grp_start
      FROM rates
      GROUP BY from_date, to_date) AS start_groups)
SELECT
  min(from_date) from_date,
  max(to_date)   to_date
FROM grouped_rates
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Why would you expect two rows in the second case and one in the first? Also, what is the definition of `"there is only one row"`?

Comment: Where there is a gap in days. From the first to the second example. ID 2 starts on the 17th no the 16th leaving a day gap between ID 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get the "why" behind the question, but I have some rough thoughts, in an ideal world you'd store `to`/`from` as interval types, but regardless you should be able to add a functional index on the table for an interval composed of `to` and `from` and just sort by that?

Comment: @JamesButler I want to be able to "book" within said dates, but you can't book across gaps of days. So booking across multiple `rates` is fine as long as they are contiguous. 
I am happy to change data structure/index etc if you have a better way of storing start/end of groups.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins ah-ha that makes sense now. I'll do some more thinking

Comment: Note: most people prefer half-open intervals ( `x >= date_from AND x < date_to` ) , which is easier in practice, avoiding all the `+1 day` - corrections in the expressions for the junction conditions and overlaps.

Comment: @joop how would that work in the CASE statement

Answer (score 2):

This is identifying contiguous overlapping groups in the data.  One approach is to find where each group begins and then do a cumulative sum.  The following query adds a flag indicating if a row starts a group:

```
select r.*,
       (case when not exists (select 1
                              from rates r2
                              where r2.from < r.from and r2.to >= r.to or
                                    (r2.from = r.from and r2.id < r.id)
                             )
             then 1 else 0 end) as StartFlag
from rate r;
```

The `or` in the correlation condition is to handle the situation where intervals that define a group overlap on the start date for the interval.

You can then do a cumulative sum on this flag and aggregate by that sum:

```
with r as (
      select r.*,
             (case when not exists (select 1
                                    from rates r2
                                    where (r2.from < r.from and r2.to >= r.to) or
                                          (r2.from = r.from and r2.id < r.id)
                                   )
                   then 1 else 0 end) as StartFlag
      from rate r
     )
select min(from), max(to)
from (select r.*,
             sum(r.StartFlag) over (order by r.from) as grp
      from r
     ) r
group by grp;
```

Comment: For simplicity sake it is safe to assume that dates are linearly consecutive. For contiguous dates `To` is always 1 day before `from`.

Comment: You mean `over (order by r.from)` (not `r2`: that's not reachable from that context -- also does not make much sense).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE prices( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , price MONEY
        , date_from DATE NOT NULL
        , date_upto DATE NOT NULL
        );

    -- some data (upper limit is EXCLUSIVE)
INSERT INTO prices(id, price, date_from, date_upto) VALUES
 ( 1,   75.00, '2015-04-12', '2016-04-16' )    
,( 2,   100.00, '2016-04-17', '2016-04-19' )
,( 3,   50.00, '2016-04-19', '2016-05-01' )
,( 4,   50.00, '2016-05-01', '2016-05-22' )
        ;

-- SELECT * FROM prices;

    -- Recursive query to "connect the dots"
WITH RECURSIVE rrr AS (
        SELECT date_from, date_upto
        , 1 AS nperiod
        FROM prices p0
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM prices nx WHERE nx.date_upto = p0.date_from)    -- no preceding segment
        UNION ALL
        SELECT r.date_from, p1.date_upto
                , 1+r.nperiod AS nperiod
        FROM prices p1
        JOIN rrr r ON p1.date_from = r.date_upto
        )
SELECT * FROM rrr r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM prices nx WHERE nx.date_from = r.date_upto)     -- no following segment
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
 date_from  | date_upto  | nperiod 
------------+------------+---------
 2015-04-12 | 2016-04-16 |       1
 2016-04-17 | 2016-05-22 |       3
(2 rows)
```